# Laravel: Fetch record from db and send it to email template

Tags: php, mysql, email, laravel-5

I have successfully implemented the sending email process in Laravel 5. Now, what I have to do is to fetch some record from database and send it to email. My send email code is:

```
 Mail::send('email', ['name' => "EE"], function($m) {
 $m->to(Input::get('email'), '')->subject('Password Request');
 });
```

The email template is:

```
Hello,

Your password has been changed, successfully.
Your new password is:"**password from database**" 
Kindly, change your password later on.

Thanks!
```

So the "password from database" has to be from database. How may I do that? any help?

Comment: Hey.. You can't grab a password from database since its encrypted. What you can do is to insert a new password and send the new password to user's email

Comment: well, i m going to do the same, but didn't care to mention because my basic problem was to get it after inserting it, and put it in the email template., Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to your question you wish to grab the password from database table,
well this not possible because password are encrypted and sending encrypted version to user is useless.

What you could do is generate a new password, save new password in database under user row, email column then email the generated password to user:

You could do this:

I assume user email address is stored under `email` column in `user table and you have a User model:

```
$email = Input::get('email');
$user = User::where('email', $email)->first();

if($user){
      $new_password = str_random(8); //generates random string , eight character long

      $user->password = \Hash::make($new_password);
      $user->save();

      $data = [
                 'name'          => $user->first_name,
                 'new_password ' => $new_password 
      ];

      Mail::send('emails.password-reset', $data, function($m) use ($user){
         $m->to($user->email, '')->subject('Password Request');
      });
}


In email template: views\emails\password-reset.blade.php:

Hello {!!$name!!},

Your password has been changed, successfully.
Your new password is:"{!!$new_password!!}" 
Kindly, change your password later on.
```

Comment: hey, I tried what u said, but i encounter this error: `Undefined variable: new_password (View: D:\Xampp\htdocs\ehsan\bkonme\resources\views\email.blade.php)`

Comment: Oh yes, it works like charm.. I was making a slight mistake in `$data` array.. +1 for sure.. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```
$userDetail = User::find(1);
Mail::send('yourTemplate', array('userInfo'=> $userDetail), function($message) {
    $message->from('from@mail.com', 'test')
        ->to('to@mail.com', 'name')
        ->subject('subject');
});
```

Then in your template file use this variable,like

```
Hello,

Your password has been changed, successfully.
Your new password is: {!! $userInfo->password !!};
Kindly, change your password later on.

Thanks!
```